# Add additional individual IAM policy to serverless yaml to extend managed policy

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis, serverless-framework

I have a managed policy that allows or read access to a kinesis stream (`AWSLambdaKinesisExecutionRole`), I am trying to add additional permissions to also allow write access to `PutRecord` and `PutRecords` on to the kinesis stream.

My serverless.yml currently looks like -

```
resources:
  Resources:
    kinesisFullAccessRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: kinesis-full-access-role
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaKinesisExecutionRole
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: kinesis-write-access
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - kinesis:PutRecord
                    - kinesis:PutRecords
                  Resource:
                    - "arn:<some_arn>:stream/inbound-message-stream-dev"
```

I am still getting a `is not authorized to perform: kinesis:PutRecord on resource` error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If your serverless is creating the IAM role by it self you should had that to the `iamRoleStatements` like shown [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam#the-default-iam-role)

but it could be easier to create an IAM role in aws console and manage that yourself, and use it like [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam#custom-iam-roles)